# Can you find the the function given the value of its definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, integral-equations

While solving a physics problem , I came across a equation that looks like this, $$\int_0^\pi \sigma(\theta)\,\sin(2\theta)\,d\theta=\frac{q}{\pi a^2} $$
Is there a way to solve for $\sigma(\theta)$. Understand that I am absolutely not familiar with these kinds of equations so maybe I am in the wrong track but I would still like to know it there is a unique or a family of solutions to this equation. q and $a^2$ are constants.

Edit:
There is one more constraint,
$$\int_0^\pi \sigma(\theta) sin(\theta)d\theta = \frac{q'}{2\pi r^2}$$
q' and r are also constants.

Comment: No.  You could add any function $F(\theta)$ to it so long as $\int_0^{\pi}F(\theta)\,\sin (2\theta)\,d\theta =0$.  Any constant works, for instance.

Comment: If you are looking for that, I think this will do the trick. $\sigma(\theta)=\frac{-2qx}{\pi^2a^2} $If you are looking for a way to solve this type of technique and find a function, I can write an interesting answer for that.

Comment: @Mostafa Yes please! Also is "x" a constant or some other function of theta?

Comment: Just a typo.  I meant this $\sigma(\theta)=\frac{-2q\theta}{\pi^2a^2}$ look that https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B-2Divide%5Bqx%2CPower%5B%CF%80%2C2%5DPower%5Ba%2C2%5D%5Dsin%5C%2840%292x%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Cpi%7D%5D

Comment: @Mostafa I have made an edit to the question. Can you please see it one more time?

Comment: Let :$\sigma(\theta)=\frac{q'}{2\pi^2r^2}\theta$

Comment: @Mostafa $\sigma(\theta)$ needs to satisfy BOTH equations

Answer (score 1):

Since we do not know anything about the function we are searching for, we will start by imposing some things that will facilitate the search process for us.

1. $\sigma(\theta) $a polynomial of degree n+1

$$I = \int ^{\pi} _{0}\sigma(\theta)\,\sin(2\theta)\,d\theta=\frac{-1}{2}(\sigma(\pi)-\sigma(0))-\frac{1}{4}\int^{\pi}_{0}\sigma^{(2)}(\theta)\sin(2\theta)d\theta$$
Therfore:
$$I=\frac{-1}{2}(\sigma(\pi)-\sigma(0))+\sum^n_{k=2}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{k+1}}(\sigma^{(2k-2)}(\pi)-\sigma^{(2k-2)}(0))  +\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\int ^{\pi}_{0}\sigma^{(2n)}(\theta)d\theta$$
we have $\sigma(\theta) $ polynomial of degree n+1 implies that $\sigma^{(n+2)}(\theta) =0\implies \sigma^{(2n)}(\theta) =0 ,$

This implies that :
$$I =\frac{-1}{2}(\sigma(\pi)-\sigma(0))+\sum^{\lfloor \frac{n+4}{4}\rfloor}_{k=2}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{k+1}}(\sigma^{(2k-2)}(\pi)-\sigma^{(2k-2)}(0))  =\frac{q}{\pi a^2}$$

Let $n=0$ (I'm going to look for a polynomial of degree 1)

Therfore:
$$I = \frac{-1}{2}(\sigma(\pi)-\sigma(0))=\frac{q}{\pi a^2}$$
This implies that :
$$\sigma(\pi)=\sigma(0)+\frac{-2q}{\pi a^2}$$

Now find the function that satisfies these conditions $\sigma(\pi)=\sigma(0)+\frac{-2q}{\pi a^2}$. It is usually assumed that: $\sigma(0)=0$

Therfore :
$$\sigma(\theta)=\begin{cases} \sigma(0)=0 \\ \sigma(\pi)=\frac{-2q}{\pi a^2}\end{cases}$$

$$\boxed{\sigma(\theta)=\frac{-2q}{\pi a^2}\theta}$$